# About limit point in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, limits

Let $(\mathbb{N},T)$ be a topological space, where $T$ is the topology generated by $\{\{2n-1,2n\}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Now, the statement : every infinite subset in $(\mathbb{N},T)$ has a limit point.

Is this statement true or false?

My try, the subset $\{2n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has no limit point, as for every $2n$ , open neighborhood $\{2n-1,2n\}$ intersects nothing other than $2n$.

So, the statement is false.

Comment: $3$ is a limit point of that set. Every neighbourhood of $3$ contains $4$ on the set and it’s a different point from $3$.

Comment: Ohhh,, sorry,,I just take the question as ,,the infinite set having limit point will be contained in the set,,,sorry ,,my bad!

Comment: @Henno Brandsma thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is non-empty let $x \in A$. If $x$ is even, $x-1$ is a limit point of $A$, and if $x$ is odd, $x+1$ is a limit point of $A$.

That $A$ is infinite is irrelevant.